# HHVM, autoload and namespace

Tags: php, autoload, hhvm

The error:

\nFatal error: Class undefined: DI in /home/runeko/www/index.php on line 7

---

My folder structure:

```
- core
  - DI.php
- index.php
```

---

index.php:

```
<?php
set_include_path( __DIR__ );
spl_autoload_extensions('.php');
spl_autoload_register();

use \core;
$di = new DI();
//i tested too:  $di = \core\DI();
```

---

DI.php

```
<?php

namespace \core;

class DI {
}
```

---

HHVM version:

```
root@akai:/var/log/hhvm# hhvm --version
HipHop VM 3.0.0-dev+2014.04.03 (rel)
Compiler: heads/master-0-g6398683df312015ebc40066dfe4b9242cc933a60
Repo schema: b4303360e484eee1f582365b9994eee150d450b0
```

---

is hhvm bugged? thanks.

**The solution:**
**This feature isn't implemented yet** ->
https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues/2308

Comment: Isn't `use \core;` suppose to actually be `use \core\DI;` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://docs.hhvm.com/manual/en/language.types.object.php

According to the official documentation, the object instantiation is not changed as in PHP, you need to use `new` keyword

```
use \core;
$di = new DI();
```

Comment: sorry miss paste and edit :( . the real index.php include the new keyword. i edit the post.

Comment: @Runeko  well, using `new` will not produce undefined FUNCTION at least :) if the autoloader does not work, it will give you `class not found` error. Are you sure, you are trying really to load the proper file, which contains the `new` keyword?

Comment: yes, i edit the error too :( hhvm doesn't find the class this the problem :'(